# options.pool.validate in sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, failover

Postgres sequence name - `post_seq`

SELECT query to get the next sequence - `select nextval(post_seq)`

Using sequelize v5.x

pool configuration -

```
{
      max: 10,
      min: 1,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
      validate: async pgClient => {
        const result = await pgClient.query('SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()');
        const isReadOnly = result.rows[0].pg_is_in_recovery;
        console.log(isReadOnly, 'isReadOnly:src/utils/db.js')
        return !isReadOnly;
      }
    }
```

Expectation -

`options.pool.validate` is called for all the queries running in the application including the above SELECT query to get the next sequence id

What's happening -

`options.pool.validate` is called only for non-SELECT queries

I am assuming this is the default behavior of sequelize. If that's the case, what would be the other way to force SELECT queries to use only writable connection? The reason for this expectation is that during AWS RDS Failover, the reader connection can't be used to run the above SELECT query since `nextval()` isn't just a select query. If there's a way to call options.pool.validate for this SELECT query, sequelize would discard that connection before making this `nextval()` query because of pool configuration used. As of now, the error I am getting in the server logs is as follows -

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction\n
```

Couple of other points to note -

1. I am connecting to cluster writer endpoint in the nodejs application
2. I am using `'SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()'` query to check whether the connection being used is read-only. If it's read-only, the connection is discarded by sequelize.
3. I have tried using `useMaster:true` in the pool config and it doesn't seem to help during the failover scenario. Probably, this is useful mainly in case of replication rather than a DR setup.